# Eclipse Java switch-case fall-through warning

Tags: java, eclipse

So I've asked my Eclipse compiler to flag such Switch Case fall-throughs as warnings:

> Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings > 'switch'
>   case fall-through: ---------------> Warning

But the compiler doesn't warn me in the below snippet. I can maybe understand not flagging `case 1`, but surely it should have flagged `case 2`? Isn't that what this preference is designed for?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 2;
    switch (a) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Yay!");
    case 5:
        System.out.println("No!");
        break;
    default:
    }
}
```

produces the output:

> Yay!
>
> No!

I tried changing the level to Error which didn't make a difference either, of course.

I'm using Eclipse Neon, BTW. Anyone else notice this behavior on their installation?

Comment: Have you been able to find a case where Eclipse does warn you about fall-through?

Comment: if you pass 1 as input then case2 will called too. so ?!

Comment: @LordFarquaad actually I was not, but the accepted answer explains why.

Comment: @Mohammad Reza Khatami Yes because there is no break; He want to get warned by his compiler. Did you restart eclipse and rebuild your project?

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhatami that's not what I intended to happen, so call it a programming mistake. I want Eclipse to warn me about it.

Comment: @beeb Yes, I did a full rebuild of the project. Actually the answer below explains what the problem was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I get the warning (Eclipse Mars). Maybe you don't have automatic compilation enabled? Or maybe you have a project specific setting which overwrites the global config setting?

Comment: It's the project specific setting overwriting the global configuration! My bad -- I have no idea how/why I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebuild your project for the warnings to take effect. I copied and pasted your `main` method as-is in one of my project files, and I can see the warning without issue. Using Neon 4.6.0.

[image]

Comment: I did rebuild the project I must say. It's the project specific setting overwriting the global configuration! My bad -- I have no idea how/why I missed it.

Comment: Good that you found the solution. I typically prefer to make these settings globally rather than making them project by project.